# Need help understanding XPATH in a specific XML example

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I posted a question last week about needing to extract some entries from xml.  I was trying to do it in a fairly manual way, and was suggested to use an xml parser.  I have been experimenting with lxml, but I can't get the hang of it (I've only just started to learn python).

An example of the XML structure is below (there would be many branches of 'ProgramInformation')

```
<TVAMain xml:lang="NL" publisher="" publicationTime="2013-09-12T01:43:09+00:00" version="217" xmlns="urn:tva:metadata:2010" xmlns:mpeg7="urn:tva:mpeg7:2008" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:tva:metadata:2010>
  <ProgramDescription>
    <ProgramInformationTable>
        <ProgramInformation programId="crid://bds.tv/95291775">
            <BasicDescription>
                <Title xml:lang="EN" type="main">Rip Off Britain</Title>
                <Synopsis xml:lang="EN" length="short">Consumer series. The team investigates why some viewers have been hit with bills they did not expect for hundreds or even thousands of pounds, and offers some advice.</Synopsis>
                <Keyword xml:lang="EN" type="main">bills</Keyword>
                <Genre href="urn:tva:metadata:cs:UPCEventGenreCS:2009:82">
                     <Name xml:lang="EN">Economics</Name>
                </Genre>
                <Language>EN</Language>
            </BasicDescription>
        </ProgramInformation>
    </ProgramInformationTable>
  </ProgramDescription>
</TVAMain>
```

I can retrieve the 'crid' and 'title':

```
tree = etree.parse('UPC_Medium.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

print (root[0][0][0].attrib)
print (root[0][0][0][0][0].text)
```

These two items would always be in the same place under each branch (so I could theoretically retrieve them in this rather crude manner).  I also need to retrieve the genre though, and that may move (as there will be a variable number of 'keyword' entries before it).

I think the key to this is XPATH, but I don't understand how to implement it (I've looked at a lot of examples on here).

Please can someone help me achieve the following:

1) Implement XPATH to retrieve and store 'crid', title and genre into separate variables (which I will write to an external file - all three need to be written together)

2) Iterate through each branch to pull out the above - there will be many thousands of entries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
nsmap = {'xmlns': 'urn:tva:metadata:2010'}

for info in root.xpath('//xmlns:ProgramInformation', namespaces=nsmap):
    print info.get('programId') # retrieve crid
    print info.find('.//xmlns:Title', namespaces=nsmap).text # retrieve title
    print info.find('.//xmlns:Genre/xmlns:Name', namespaces=nsmap).text # retrieve genre
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  That worked a treat.  So my understanding is that in the first line (nsmap), I choose a unique value at the top of the tree and give it a name (xmlns).  The second line sets the 'root' of where I'm working from, and the subsequent lines work relative to that root.  I therefore assume that any other tags that I want to pull out are specified as .//xmlns:tag_name/xmlns:next_level_tag_name. Is that correct?

Comment: @Nick, See [`lxml.etree Tutorial - namespaces`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces).